# How do I change date display from 2017-03-20 to March 20, 2017?

Tags: civimail, dates

Writing "Please Renew" letters to membership. Template text includes a token for the expiration date {membership.end_date}. In pdf printout, date converts to **number format** (yr-mo-day), even though in the Membership summary the date reads in **calendar format**. Is there some way to change the setting for this?

How it reads: "Thank you for supporting our organization! Your Family Membership is expiring on **2017-03-20**." What I want: "Thank you for supporting our organization! Your Family Membership is expiring on **March 20, 2017**"